# Map - Single key with multiple values

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

Well, I have a list called listaParcelasGerarOrcamento, and it contains the following items:

```
05/03/2015 Parcela 2/5 32.00
12/03/2015 Parcela 3/5 32.00
19/03/2015 Parcela 4/5 32.00
26/02/2015 Parcela 1/5 32.00
26/02/2015 Parcela 1/9 12.00
26/03/2015 Parcela 5/5 32.00
28/03/2015 Parcela 2/9 12.00
28/04/2015 Parcela 3/9 12.00
28/05/2015 Parcela 4/9 12.00
....
```

And I need to put them in a HashMap, I am using the date as the key and trying to put the other party in a list and pass as value, but in the case of the day 02.26.2015 it only adds the second item and not both.

```
    Map<String, List<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas>> mapa = new HashMap<String, List<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.size(); i++) {

        List<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas> listaItens = new ArrayList<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas>();

        ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas itensParcela = new ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas();

        itensParcela.setDataPagamento(listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i)
                .getDataPagamento());
        itensParcela.setDescricaoParcela("Descricao "
                + listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i).getDescricaoParcela());
        itensParcela.setValorParcela(listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i)
                .getValorParcela());
        listaItens.add(itensParcela);

        mapa.put(listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i).getDataPagamento(),
                listaItens);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a multimap.  Several libraries provide them, but I prefer Guava myself.

If you want to simulate it, then this line

```
mapa.put(listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i).getDataPagamento(),
                listaItens);
```

Needs to change to something like this

```
String keya = listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i).getDataPagamento();

List<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas> lista = mapa.get(keya);
if (lista == null) {
  lista = new ArrayList<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas>();
  mapa.put(keya, lista);
}
lista.addAll(listaItens);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're recreating your `ArrayList<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas>` in each *iteration* of the `for` loop, as well as re-inserting the new list into the map. You need to create the list upon seeing a particular key for the first time, and *then* add items to the list.

So the end result will look like this:

```
Map<String, List<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas>> mapa = new HashMap<String, List<ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas>>();

for (int i = 0; i < listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.size(); i++) {
    String key = listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i).getDataPagamento();

    ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas itensParcela = new ItensDespesaOrcamentoParcelas();
    itensParcela.setDataPagamento(key);
    itensParcela.setDescricaoParcela("Descricao " + listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i).getDescricaoParcela());
    itensParcela.setValorParcela(listaParcelasGerarOrcamento.get(i).getValorParcela());

    if(mapa.get(key) == null)
        mapa.put(key, new ArrayList<>());

    mapa.get(key).add(itensParcela);
}
```